# nested lapply performance, how to optimise?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of `data.frames`. Within each data.frame I want to split by a grouping (`z`) run a function, put the results back together, then put all the results of the of the nested `lapply` together in a data.frame, then flatten the list of result `data.frame`s into one `data.frame`.

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:200, 30000, replace = TRUE), 
                y = sample(1:200, 30000, replace = TRUE), 
                z = sample(LETTERS, 30000, replace = TRUE))

alist <- list(df,df,df) # longer in real life
answer <- lapply(alist, function(q) {
    a <- split(q,q$z)
    result.1 <- lapply(a, function(w) {
        neww <- cbind(w[,1],w[,2])
        result.2 <- colSums(neww)
    })
    ldply(result.1)
})
# cor(neww) can actually be a variey of foos I just use cor() for easy reproducibility
ldply(answer)
```

This has some really tough memory usage and is also slow. Thanks to @Andrie I know how to clear my workspace before I start like:

```
 rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "alist"))
```

But is there a way to modify my approach like junking `w` in the second `lapply` etc to try reduce memory usage and speed things up? In this case `foo` likes a matrix and so `data.table` won't be my answer. In other `foo`s I will need all `w` and class will need to be a `data.frame`

Comment: Please make your code reproducible. You need to show `foo`.

Comment: One strategy is probably to combine all `data.frame`s into one `data.table` and then split-apply-combine that.

Comment: I am using many `foo`s for argument you can makes it `cor`. My focus was on the code surrounding `foo` but perhaps then I am missing the point.

Comment: The point is to make it easy to answer. For that I need to be able to compare my result with yours. That means your code should run when copied into my R session.

Comment: @Roland, just noticed that you mentioned the `data.table` solution as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ldply(alist, ddply, "z", summarize, xy.foo = foo(x, y))
```

If you want `x` and `y` to show up in your final data.frame, replace `summarize` with `transform`. Also, looking at your `foo` usage, you might have to replace `(x, y)` with `cbind(x, y)`.

Also, I would recommend you profile your code. In the end, `foo` might be what is slowing you down, not the split/combine part.

Comment: +1 thanks @ flodel this looks clearly less verbose and appealing and seems to save on the `ldply`s but I thought I should naturally steer away from `ddply` when thinking of speed. Is part of the memory saving here less explicit object creation? if you want to add any short explanation I would be greatful. And for sure `foo` is the horrible bottleneck, but hard to change. Therefore the surrounding approach to `foo` was my focus.

Comment: @user1320502 If `foo` is the real bottleneck, parallelization might be the way to go.

Comment: And if parallelization is the way to go, `plyr` does have that ability built in. See the `.parallel` argument and related arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Why aren't you use `ddply` and `llply` from `plyr` but only `ldply`??

```
# Note: @Flodel has a very nice, simple one-line plyr solution
# Please use that.
out <- ldply(alist, function(q) {
    ddply(q, .(z), function(w) {
        neww <- w[, -3]
        result.2 <- colSums(neww) # dummy function
    })
})
```

The first `ldply` passes elements of list `alist` one by one. Each time `q` is therefore the `data.frame` contained in each element of the `list`. Then, within this, we would like to split by `z`. Since the input is `q` is a `data.frame` and output also should be a `data.frame` we use `ddply` with the second argument `.(z)` to split by `z`. Here, you do your calculations, return whatever you want (`colSums` in this case). The `ldply` returns as a `data.frame`.

`Data.table` solution: An alternative *fast* solution would be to use a `data.table` on the combined `data.frame` which can be achieved as follows (what @Roland mentioned in his comments as well):

```
require(data.table)
# for creating a group 
group <- vapply(alist, nrow, integer(1))
dt <- data.table(do.call(rbind, alist))
# create group
dt[ , grp := rep(1:3, group)]
setkey(dt, "grp", "z")
# call your function (here column means)
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by="grp,z"]
# or if its correlation
dt[, list(cor_x_y = cor(x,y)), by="grp,z"]
```

Comment: isn't `ldply(llply(...))` just the same thing as `ldply(...)`, so you can save unnecessary processing?

Comment: Also, you don't need to define a `function(q)ddply(q, ...)` function on the fly, just use a straight `ddply, ...` like I did.

Comment: you are right on both occasions. The first one, I use it this way because I have observed this to be faster than just using a `ldply`, but maybe its a wrong hunch (I'll test it). And the 2nd comment, very true, there is no need to do it my way! thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I'll leave the solution as such. Else it'll be identical to yours. It could serve as a `how-not-to` write a `plyr` function :)

Comment: Just swapped `sapply` for `vapply` because `sapply` behaves weirdly with empty input lists.